# Why this label is rendered twice?

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, libktx

I use [ktx](https://github.com/libktx/ktx).

I have the code below:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseScreen(val game: PKGame) : KtxScreen {
    val stage: Stage

    init {
        stage = PStage(ScreenViewport())
        Gdx.input.inputProcessor = stage
    }

    override fun render(delta: Float) {
        stage.act()
        stage.draw()
    }

    override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int) {
        stage.viewport.update(width, height, true)
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        stage.dispose()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class LoadingScreen(game: PKGame): BaseScreen(game) {
    val loadingState by lazy { scene2d.visLabel("Loading...") }

    override fun show() {
        TextureAssets.entries.forEach { game.assets.load(it) }

        stage.actors {
            visTable {
                center()
                setFillParent(true)

                add(loadingState)
                row()
                visLabel("Click to start game")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun render(delta: Float) {
        game.assets.update()

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched && game.assets.isFinished) {
            game.addScreen(MainMenu(game))
            game.setScreen<MainMenu>()
            game.removeScreen<LoadingScreen>()
            dispose()
        }

        if (game.assets.isFinished) {
            loadingState.setText("Finished")
        }
        debug { stage.actors.toString() }

        super.render(delta)
    }
}
```

Why it showed twice? And how can I fix this problem?

[image: 图片.png]

It is expected that the label "Click to start game" show just once.

I hove tried removing the code

```kotlin
if (game.assets.isFinished) {
    loadingState.setText("Finished")
}
```

but it still happened.

Then, I tried removing `add(loadingState)` and it rendered as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by rendered twice? You can see it in two places on the screen at once?

Comment: Yes. I have already uploaded the result image and the code of `BaseScreen`.

Comment: I don't use Screen or the libKTX Scene2D stuff, but my best guess is that your `show()` is gettting called more than once so the table is added to your scene twice. This would explain why they aren't overlapping, but just one under the other. Maybe something to do with how you're using a base class (which IMO should be avoided for something as monolithic as a whole screen because it breaks the *composition before inheritance* principle). I would set a breakpoint in there and use the debugger to see if it's getting called twice and if so, from where.

Comment: It seems that you are right.When I move the codes from `show()` into `init`, it shows as expected.

Comment: If that worked to fix it, there is probably still a lurking bug in your BaseScreen class.